# Explanation of the execution order when using ES6 imports?

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules, circular-dependency

I'm working on an ES6 project with webpack, and after deleting an unused import
in one of a completely unrelated file, it surfaced a circular dependency problem.

This is vaguely original code, which does not work. Since it does not load due to the circular dependency,
I could not figure out what was actually happening. I believe it did print out just "A" before erroring.

```js
// A.js
import B from 'B';
const B = getB();
export default B;

// B.js
import C from 'C';
function getB() {
    useC(C);
}
export default getB;

// C.js
import D from 'D';
function useC() {
    D();
}
export default useC;

// D.js
import A from 'A';
function D() {
    const aThing = a.thing();
}
export default D;
```

This was the original code, which does not work. Since it does not load due to the circular dependency,
I could not figure out what was actually happening. I believe it did print out just "A" before erroring.

I changed it to this

```js
// A.js
import B from 'B';
import C from 'C';
const B = getB(C);
export default B;

// B.js
function getB(C) {
    useC(C);
}
export default getB;

// C.js
import D from 'D';
function useC() {
    D();
}
export default useC;

// D.js
import A from 'A';
function D() {
    const aThing = a.thing();
}
export default D;
```

When I print an execution order on the modules, it shows B D C A.
From what I read from various answers, it seems like when D imports A,
it shortcircuits that call and begins just processing it's own body, because the use of A is in a function.
Why can the former not shortcircuit the import of A for the function like the latter, if that's what it's doing?